# Start program and get process id

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

In batch file I can start a program in parallel to current session via

```
start "" notepad.exe
```

but I need to get a handle of the process I've started. How can I get it?

Comment: What's a handle? Is that like a PID?

Comment: @SomethingDark, yes, process id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off

:: set your own command here
set "command=notepad"
set "workdir=."

set "ReturnValue="
set "ProcessId="
for /f " skip=5 eol=} tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('wmic process call create "%command%"^,"%workdir%"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=;  " %%c in ("%%a") do (
        set "%%c=%%d"
    )
)



if not %ReturnValue%==0 (
    echo some kind of error - error code %ReturnValue%
) else if defined ProcessId echo PID -^> %ProcessId%
```

delims in this line `for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=;     "` should be `for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=;<tab><space>"` and I don't know if the tab will correctly copied.You also need to check if your editor replaces tab with spaces.Check also [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/ProcessesUtils/StartPID.bat).

Comment: Great! Unfortunately didn't get it working, but idea with `wmic` and `for` was very helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: `Непредвиденное появление: (.` - something like `Unexpected occurrence: (.` https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSpX2.png

Comment: Also it does not use current directory for the process started: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCZKp.png

Comment: @Qwertiy - if you start it as administrator the dir is automatically changes to system32. You can change the workdir to `%~dp0`  . The error looks like syntax error which is strange. YOu can delete the `echo off` line to see what happens in the console.

Comment: @Qwertiy - I've copied the snipped and had the same problem.Then deleted delimiters on the inner loop and entered them again `;<tab><space>` . Stackoverflow editor changes the tabs I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154274/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-npocmaka).

Comment: Not work wmic not found(in win 10 pro). And what if i have many runed notepads?

Comment: @nim the `wmic` location is `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\` . You can check if the directory exists and if it is in the `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @npocmaka [answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/46183728/4928642) found the other solution:

```
@echo off

set pid=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in ('wmic process call create "notepad.exe"^,"%~dp0." ^| find "ProcessId"') do set pid=%%a
echo %pid%

timeout 5
taskkill /pid %pid%
```

Comment: great.I wanted to avoid usage of `FIND` in order to make the script faster.

Comment: I'm [trying to make this run](https://superuser.com/questions/1340565/getting-invalid-format-error-when-running-an-executable-with-parameters) while passing multiple parameters for the process I am starting but it's just won't work. Any idea what the problem might be?